# MFC tree control notification is triggered twice

Tags: c++, loops, mfc, treecontrol

My problem is that the following function is called twice:

```
ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGED, IDC_TREE1, &MainHamsterDlg::OnClickTree)

void MainHamsterDlg::OnClickTree(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    CTreeCtrl* pCtrl = (CTreeCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_TREE1);
    HTREEITEM hItem = pCtrl->GetSelectedItem();
    BOOL hItemm = pCtrl->ItemHasChildren(hItem);
    if (hItem && hItemm)
    {
        HTREEITEM hChild = pCtrl->GetChildItem(hItem);
        pCtrl->SelectItem(hChild);                           <--- Cause of the "loop"
    }

    *pResult = 1;
}
```

I need my code to automatically go to a child element of the tree. (In future I will write some code to detect what has been selected and it will cause some actions.)

My code works correctly when I click on a leaf, because:

```
if (hItem && hItemm)
```

ensures that:

```
pCtrl->SelectItem(hChild);
```

won't be executed. How can I make my code work when an internal node is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a dirty hack, but it should prevent your code from being executed twice. Add the following member to your class:

```
bool ignoreNextSelChange = false;
```

Then modify your function as follows:

```
void MainHamsterDlg::OnClickTree(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    if (ignoreNextSelChange)
    {
        // Don't do anything, but make sure that the else block below will be executed
        // again with the next (expected) call of this function.
        ignoreNextSelChange = false;
    }
    else
    {
        CTreeCtrl* pCtrl = (CTreeCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_TREE1);
        HTREEITEM hItem = pCtrl->GetSelectedItem();
        BOOL hItemm = pCtrl->ItemHasChildren(hItem);
        if (hItem && hItemm)
        {
            HTREEITEM hChild = pCtrl->GetChildItem(hItem);

            // Make sure that this else block won't be executed again when the function
            // SelectItem() is called below.
            ignoreNextSelChange = true;

            pCtrl->SelectItem(hChild);
        }
    }
    *pResult = 1;
}
```

Comment: yes I was thinking about that solution... perhaps I must use it.. maybe someone will write better solution but for now its ok for me. thx

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found some code where I solved a similar problem. In that code I handled [`TVN_SELCHANGING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `TVN_SELCHANGED`:

```
ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGING, IDC_TREE1, &MainHamsterDlg::OnSelChanging)

void MainHamsterDlg::OnSelChanging(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    // Initially assume that the selection change is allowed.
    *pResult = 0;

    CTreeCtrl* pCtrl = (CTreeCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_TREE1);
    HTREEITEM hItem = pCtrl->GetSelectedItem();
    BOOL hItemm = pCtrl->ItemHasChildren(hItem);
    if (hItem && hItemm)
    {
        // Set *pResult to TRUE to prevent the selection from changing.
        *pResult = TRUE;

        // Make an own selection.
        HTREEITEM hChild = pCtrl->GetChildItem(hItem);
        pCtrl->SelectItem(hChild);
    }
}
```

Calling `SelectItem()` in the `TVN_SELCHANGING` message handler doesn't cause a problem for me.